# Isomorphism between complex tori and complex elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the following proof in Joseph H. Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves". The author is showing that the map $\phi:\mathbb{C}/\Lambda\to E(\mathbb{C})$ defined as $z\longmapsto[\wp(z),\wp'(z),1]$ is a complex analytic isomorphism of Lie groups. The part that's tripping me up is showing that the map actually is a group homomorphism. Here is how his argument goes.

Using previous propositions, he shows there exists a function $f(z)\in\mathbb{C}(\Lambda)$ such that $\text{div}(f)=(z_1+z_2)-(z_1)-(z_2)+(0)$. Since $\mathbb{C}(\Lambda)=\mathbb{C}(\wp,\wp')$, we have that there exists an $F\in\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ where $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is viewed as $\mathbb{C}(E)$. We then have $\text{div}(F)=(\phi(z_1+z_2)) - (\phi(z_1)) - (\phi(z_2)) + (\phi(0))$. He then invokes Corollary 3.5 which tells us that since $\text{div}(F)$ is principal, $\phi(z_1+z_2)-\phi(z_1)-\phi(z_2)+\phi(0)=O_E$, where $O_E$ is the identity on our elliptic curves. Re-arranging the terms, I get $$\phi(z_1+z_2)+\phi(0)=\phi(z_1)+\phi(z_2)$$ so we're almost done but I don't know how to show $\phi(0)=0$. I have shown that $\phi$ is bijective but without the morphism property, I don't know how to conclude. Can anyone help shed some light on this proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to remember that $E$ is sitting in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^2$. You've indicated that by writing the map $\phi$ using homogeneous coordinates $\phi(z)=[\wp(z),\wp'(z),1]$. So just as when working with algebraic maps, you need to take local coordinates that make sense at your point before evaluating. So as a map on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, if you want to know what $\phi$ looks like near $0\bmod\Lambda$, you can't just plug in $z=0$ since, as Angina Seng indicated, both $\wp$ and $\wp'$ have poles at $z=0$. But since $\phi$ is written using homogeneous coordinates, it is also given by the formula
$$ \phi(z)=[z^3\wp(z),z^3\wp'(z),z^3]  $$
at all points of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ where these three coordinate functions are (1) well-defined and (2) don't all vanish. Then using
$$  z^3\wp(z)\Big|_{z=0}=0, \quad z^3\wp'(z)\Big|_{z=0}=-1,\quad z^3\Big|_{z=0}=0, $$
we get $\phi(0)=[0,1,0]=\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I didn't realize immediately being in projective space allowed for the expression to be rewritten in those terms. If I understand correctly, it's because $z$ is fixed that we can just pull out $z^3$ here, which allows us to properly evaluate the function there.

Comment: @Saegusa ",,,we can just pull out  $z^3$,,," Sort of. More formally, you're working in the category of complex manifolds, so the morphisms are maps that are locally represented by holomorphic functions, i.e., by convergent complex power series. So if you want to know what's happening near $0$, you need to look at a neighborhood of $[0,1,0]$ on $E$. Local coordinates there are $(X/Y,Z/Y)$, so near $0\in\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, your map is $(\wp(z)/\wp'(z),1/\wp'(z))$. Both of these meromorphic functions are in fact holomorphic at $0$, and indeed they vanish at $0$.

Comment: So in this category, the maps aren't holomorphic, they are only locally holomorphic? I thought that in say, the category of smooth manifolds, the map would be smooth, not locally smooth.

Comment: @Saegusa A map between complex manifolds is holomorphic if every point has a neighborhood in which the map is given by an absolutely convergent power series. The definition needs to be local. (Just as the definition of differentiable map of a real manifold is a local definition.) How else would you define holomorphic, since the definition of complex manifold is a bunch of local pieces that look like (say) $\{z\in\mathbb C:|z|<1\}$, with holomorphic transition maps?

Answer (score 2):

$\wp(z)\sim 1/z^2$ as $z\to0$ and $\wp'(z)\sim -2/z^3$. For small nonzero $z$,
$$\phi(z)=[\wp(z),\wp'(z),1]=[z^3\wp(z),z^3\wp'(z),z^3]\to[0,-2,0]=[0,1,0]$$
as $z\to0$. So we define $\phi$ at the poles of $\wp$ by defining $\phi(0)=[0,1,0]$
in the projective plane, which is the zero point $O_E$ of the elliptic curve $E$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Does that mean that we're defining $\phi$ to behave a certain way? I thought it would drop out of the definition directly.

Comment: The definition $\phi(z)=[\wp(z),\wp'(z),1]$ only makes sense for the non-zero elements of $\Bbb C/\Lambda$. We need to define it for the zero element. The right definition is $\phi(0)=O_E$: for a start, it's the only one that makes it continuous....

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense, thanks for your help!